# Javascript is not working when page reloads

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Daftar Berita </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
          content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php include 'formpencarian.html.php'; ?>

    <div id="newssection" style="margin-top: 50px; clear: both; display: block;">
        <?php include 'newssection.php'; ?>
    </div>

    <?php
            if(isset($_POST["cari"])){
                echo "<div id='searchsection' style='margin-top: 50px; clear: both; display: block;'>";
                include 'search.php';
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<script>document.getElementById('newssection').style.display = 'none';</script>";
            }
    ?>

    <script>
        function showMore(id){
            document.getElementById('isi'+id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('more'+id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('less'+id).style.display = "block";
        }

        function showLess(id){
            document.getElementById('isi'+id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('more'+id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('less'+id).style.display = "none";
        }

        function advancedSearch(){
            document.getElementById('advanced').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('searching').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('no').style.display = "block";
        }

        function noSearch(){
            document.getElementById('advanced').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('searching').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('no').style.display = "none";
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

basically, the search.php file contains mysql query for displaying results.

the problem is, when this page reloaded (because i sent the POST variable to this page) the javascript doesn't work. as a result, i can't show or hide certain divs on my results page (because the results page is formatted just the same as this page).

Am i doing something wrong?? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what part of you js does not work? the one within php or the bigger one with functions?

Comment: the inner one is working. the bigger one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

in the bigger JS part there are only function **definitions**, but now **calls** - to make them run in any case, you need to call them, like:

```
noSearch();
advancedSearch();
```

and this part doesn't seem to be related to `$_POST` checking
..
to avoid not calling them in search.php, you should remove `if(isset($_POST["cari"])){` check from your main file and do it inside of the search.php

Comment: i have called them in the file search.php, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I was basing my proposal on the code that was presented. How can we know that there's smth in search.php? made edits now, check